# inserting in certain parts of the string

Tags: java, string, calculator

I would like to insert spaces in certain parts of my string.
I'm writing a program fora calculator.

For example, for the string

`"23+45"` I want it to be `"23 + 45"`.

Or `"1+(4*8)"` as `"1 + ( 4 * 8 )"`.

I'm doing this so that I can split the string according to the spaces,

I'm using the Shunting Yard algorithm, so I need to tokenise the input.

Comment: Your question is....  and your code which attempts this looks like .... but it does .... instead of what you expected which is ....??

Comment: Right now I'm inserting spaces in the input itself. So I dont really have a code for this yet. I've written the rest of the program but thats not really related to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simple.

```
"23+45".replaceAll("[+*()]", " $0 ").trim();
```

The `trim()` trims any trailing space.

You can include other operators as so:

```
"23+(45*-30/2)".replaceAll("[+*()-/]", " $0 ").trim();
```

Comment: This could result in multiple whitespaces in the string, another `replaceAll` could be done instead of the trim to trim the other whitespaces too: `"23+45".replaceAll("[-/+*()]", " $0 ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`

Comment: @HarryJoy Updated my answer, thanks. But I think `-` should not be separated by a space if used as a sign. Using it as an operator, space is fine. Which looks better? `2 * -4` or `2 * - 4`?

Comment: @SavK it is the 0th capturing group or "everything" that the RegEx has matched.

Answer (score 0):

The idea for adding spaces because of splitting the String purpose, than you can also split the string by arithmetic operators also using `Class StringTokenizer`.
For more about [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: I don't see any point in using `StringTokenizer` in modern Java.

Comment: This is an example that you can try:
String msg = "1+(4*8)";        
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msg,"+*/-");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
      System.out.println(st.nextToken());

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. You had to write 4 lines and it still doesn't give me the final string. To do that, you've to add another 3 lines to use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

SavK,

inserting tokens and then parsing them again seems to be extra useless operations. (neverseless, regex solution above is just short and fine (+1 from me)) Alternatively you can provide tokens directly to Shunting Yard algorithm (that needs tokens as input).

Try to look over [StreamTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) class (since JDK 1.0) to parse expression for tokens. It does all parsing you need to return tokens to you (and even more: gets numbers as integer number tokens).

Here is primitive demo.

```
package core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Q {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamTokenizer stok = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader("1+(40*8)"));
    stok.parseNumbers();
    try {
        while(stok.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            System.out.println("nval: "+stok.nval);
            System.out.println("sval: "+stok.sval);
            System.out.println("ttype: "+stok.ttype);
            System.out.println("toString: "+stok.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```